# Get the number of a .class for each <h4>

Tags: jquery, cheerio

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="ratings">
    <h4>
        <a href="https://www.horoscope.com/star-ratings/today/aquarius">
Sex 
            <i class="icon-star-filled highlight"></i>
            <i class="icon-star-filled highlight"></i>
            <i class="icon-star-filled highlight"></i>
            <i class="icon-star-filled"></i>
            <i class="icon-star-filled"></i>
        </a>
    </h4>
    <h4>
        <a href="https://www.horoscope.com/star-ratings/today/aquarius">
Hustle 
            <i class="icon-star-filled highlight"></i>
            <i class="icon-star-filled highlight"></i>
            <i class="icon-star-filled highlight"></i>
            <i class="icon-star-filled"></i>
            <i class="icon-star-filled"></i>
        </a>
    </h4>
    <h4>
        <a href="https://www.horoscope.com/star-ratings/today/aquarius">
Vibe 
            <i class="icon-star-filled highlight"></i>
            <i class="icon-star-filled highlight"></i>
            <i class="icon-star-filled highlight"></i>
            <i class="icon-star-filled"></i>
            <i class="icon-star-filled"></i>
        </a>
    </h4>
    <h4>
        <a href="https://www.horoscope.com/star-ratings/today/aquarius">
Success 
            <i class="icon-star-filled highlight"></i>
            <i class="icon-star-filled highlight"></i>
            <i class="icon-star-filled"></i>
            <i class="icon-star-filled"></i>
            <i class="icon-star-filled"></i>
        </a>
    </h4>
</div>
```

I want to get with cheerio per h4 the number of elements with class `.highlight`.

To accomplish this I did the following:

```
let $ = cheerio.load(response.data);
let zodiacRatings = $('.ratings>h4');

let ratings = [];

rawZodiacRatings.map((key, val) => {
    let $ = cheerio.load(val);
    ratings.push($('.highlight').length);
});

console.log(ratings);
```

This returns:

`[ 3, 3, 3, 2 ]` which is what I want.

But I think there is a better way to get the number of `.highlight` for each `<h4>`. I know I can use `return $('.highlight').length` in the map(), but that does give me back more information than just: `[ 3, 3, 3, 2 ]`.

Comment: jQuery? or Cheerio? Also please fix the sample HTML. Use neutral category names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this? At some point yr gonna need to switch it from an array of jQuery selectors to an array.

```
//switch it from jquery selectors to an actual array
let zodiacRatings = $('.ratings>h4').toArray();
//return a new array with the number lengths selected.
let ratings = zodiacRatings.map(x=>{
     return $(x).find('.highlight').length
 })  

console.log(ratings)
```

Answer (score 1):

More concise is:

```
$('h4').map((i, el) => $(el).find('.highlight').length).get()
```

or

```
$('h4').get().map((el) => $(el).find('.highlight').length)
```

Note the cheerio map (first one) has an extra i param which is annoying but is often useful to do it that way.